# Optimizing SQLite inserts

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, cursor, content-values

I have a this function below which is working fine:

I use it because in a *synchronisation process* I have to insert a lot of rows (sometimes more than 30 000 in the same sync) in different tables and for some of them, the value I recieve from my `Json` object is not the real one. So before inserting the row, **I have to replace the value with another**. That is why I use this function:

```
public void myFunction( String tableName, String attrName, ContentValues currentVal ) { 

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long realValue = -1;

    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT value FROM "+tableName+" WHERE "+tableName+".other_value = " + currentVal.getAsString(attrName), null);

    if( c.moveToFirst() ) { 
        realValue = c.getLong(0);
    }
    if( c != null ) c.close();

    currentVal.put( attrName, realValue );  

}
```

My problem is the `Cursor`... The `c.moveToFirst()` function 
affects the speed of the process.

*I did researches and I found so many explanations like :*

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15738831/5778152

**I specify that I use indexes and I already try transactions.**

So, what I wanted to do now (or to know) is:
Is there a way to perform something like:

```
currentVal.put( attrName, SELECT value FROM "+tableName+" WHERE "+tableName+".other_value = " + currentVal.getAsString(attrName) );
```

Because with this trick I will not have to iterate into my `Cursor` (which is actually my problem) and when I will insert the content of the `ContentValues` it will automatically process the sub-query to retrieve the real value to insert.

I also thought about **creating a temporary table**. I insert the values founded in my `Json` object without changing them and when I've inserted all the values for the current table, I copy them into the real table unsing in the same time a sub-query to relpace the incorrect values by the correct ones.

*Any ideas, suggestions, snippets, ... will be appreciated*

Comment: The best approach I've tried inserting over 100,000 elements onto SQLite is using it through NDK layer, and using some simple native code to access and write onto DB which is quite fast in comparison to application layer writing.

Comment: Inserts do not take much time, the problem is in the replacement part because until now I didn't found how to go through this without using the `cursor.moveToFirst()` function

Comment: You must finally `cursor.close()` after every operation. Then reopen `cursor` object. Are you doing it?

Comment: Are you using the *right* indexes? Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for the SELECT query.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the right indexes. In my question I said it was for 30 000 rows but this amount of rows is almost the same for each tables (about 15). So the sync operation is taking between 40min to 2hours... Sorry, I can't show the output of the EXPLAIN QUARY PLAN but the bottleneck is the `cursor.moveToFirst()`

Comment: Why can't you show the EQP for that query?

Comment: Because I will have to execute a some scriptsbefore starting the sync process and it's not possible actually. Really sorry...

Comment: You don't need the real DB or real data; what matters is the DB structure.

Comment: Hum, ok. And you also don't need it for each different queries? Because queries can be different depending on the parameters of the function...

Comment: I want to see the EQP output for those queries that are too slow for you. (And what did you measure?)

Comment: All of them are too slow for me :D 1 by 1 it's not that slow but when you have 30 000 values to insert for 15 different tables it's taking long. I give you the EQP asap

Comment: How slow is "not that slow"?

Comment: Think it was something like 0.03s but I didn't measure it, it was a 
colleague (my tables contains between 1 000 000 and 5 000 000 rows)